# GLPK linear programming

Tags: python, python-2.7, linear-programming, glpk

I am working on some very large scale linear programming problems.  (Matrices are currently roughly 1000x1000 and these are the 'mini' ones.)

I thought that I had the program running successfully, only I have realized that I am getting some very unintuitive answers. For example, let's say I were to maximize x+y+z subject to a set of constraints x+y<10 and y+z <5.  I run this and get an optimal solution.  Then, I run the same equation but with different constraints: x+y<20 and y+z<5.  Yet in the second iteration, my maximization decreases!

I have painstakingly gone through and assured myself that the constraints are loading correctly.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

I found something in the documentation about lpx_check_kkt which seems to tell you when your solution is likely to be correct or high confidence (or low confidence for that matter), but I don't know how to use it.

I made an attempt and got the error message lpx_check_kkt not defined.

I am adding some code as an addendum in hopes that someone can find an error. 
The result of this is that it claims an optimal solution has been found. And yet every time I raise an upper bound, it gets less optimal.
I have confirmed that my bounds are going up and not down.

```
    size = 10000000+1
    ia = intArray(size)
    ja = intArray(size)
    ar = doubleArray(size)
    prob = glp_create_prob()

    glp_set_prob_name(prob, "sample")
    glp_set_obj_dir(prob, GLP_MAX)
    glp_add_rows(prob, Num_constraints)
    for x in range(Num_constraints):
            Variables.add_variables(Constraints_for_simplex)
            glp_set_row_name(prob, x+1, Variables.variers[x])
            glp_set_row_bnds(prob, x+1, GLP_UP, 0, Constraints_for_simplex[x][1])
            print 'we set the row_bnd for', x+1,' to ',Constraints_for_simplex[x][1]
    glp_add_cols(prob, len(All_Loops))
    for x in range(len(All_Loops)):
            glp_set_col_name(prob, x+1, "".join(["x",str(x)]))
            glp_set_col_bnds(prob,x+1,GLP_LO,0,0)
            glp_set_obj_coef(prob,x+1,1)
    for x in range(1,len(All_Loops)+1):
            z=Constraints_for_simplex[0][0][x-1]
            ia[x] = 1; ja[x] = x;  ar[x] = z
    x=len(All_Loops)+1
    while x<Num_constraints + len(All_Loops):
    for y in range(2, Num_constraints+1):
                    z=Constraints_for_simplex[y-1][0][0]
                    ia[x] = y; ja[x] =1 ; ar[x] = z
                    x+=1
    x=Num_constraints+len(All_Loops)
    while x <len(All_Loops)*(Num_constraints-1):
            for z in range(2,len(All_Loops)+1):
                    for y in range(2,Num_constraints+1):
                            if x<len(All_Loops)*Num_constraints+1:
                                    q = Constraints_for_simplex[y-1][0][z-1]
                                    ia[x] = y ; ja[x]=z; ar[x] = q
                                    x+=1


    glp_load_matrix(prob, len(All_Loops)*Num_constraints, ia, ja, ar)
    glp_exact(prob,None)
    Z = glp_get_obj_val(prob)
```

Comment: Did you set the objective direction to maximization? The default is minimization and based on what you say it looks like you did not, or at least it would explain why your objective is decreasing.

Comment: I know - I thought the same thing! But I have checked and triple checked.  It's so bizarre to me.  The code is rather cumbersome, hence why I didn't post it, but perhaps I should. I feel I must be doing something wrong. I will see if I can find a useful chunk of my code to post.

Answer (score 4):

Start by solving your problematic instances with different solvers and checking the objective function value. If you can export your model to .mps format (I don't know how to do this with GLPK, sorry), you can upload the mps file to http://www.neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html and solve it with several different LP solvers.

Comment: Thanks so much - I will give that a try - I just read some research that says the two open source solvers of which GLPK is one have very poor accuracy in the "optimal" department, so maybe it isn't my implementation. Only correct 4 and 7% of the time. I found that a little shocking! Of course if the solution they find happens to be 95% of the way there but not optimal, that wouldn't be so bad, but in this particular instance that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Can you post where you found the 4% statistic? That's surprising. Is the other open-source solver you refer to CLP? Also, I can give you more troubleshooting ideas once you've checked other solvers.

Comment: So sorry I'm just seeing this! Life took a chaotic turn.  Any troubleshooting ideas would be very appreciated! Here is the survey I was referencing - neon.vb.cbs.nl/casc/..%5Ccasc%5CESSNet2%5Cdeliverable_solverstudy.pdf

Comment: No ideas as of now... if possible update the question with the results of trying to solve your model with a different solver. Also, where in that paper are the 4% and 7% statistics? I'm not seeing anything about solvers providing the wrong solution.

Comment: The quote is at the bottom of page 6:A very interesting fact is that GLKP and LP SOLVE only manage to calculate optimal solutions for 3 or rather 5 of the 87 problem instances

Comment: I see. The paper isn't saying that GLPK reported non-optimal solutions as optimal. What it is saying is that for most of the instances GLPK had not yet found the optimal solution after an hour of running time. GLPK is slow, but not necessarily inaccurate.